# Why doesn't app.config get added after installing from windows installer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, app-config

I have a Windows application developed using Visual Studio 2008 (C#).
It has a app.config file, where various configuration related information are kept. After creating an installer for the project and installing it, there are no app.config file being copied to the installed directory. However, the functionalities that rely on settings in this file seem to work.

Now one of these settings is a database connection string, which obviously needs changing when installed in a different PC. My question is, how to have the app.config file available with the Setup file so that it can be configured later?

Comment: Is it possible that the config file has the same name as your exe/dll file, with a config extension?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The app.config is copied/renamed <assembly name>.config as part of the compilation process, and placed in the bin directory. If you're using a Visual Studio Installer project (*blech*!), then it should have picked it up also and included it in the installer, IIRC.

(In response to your comment to both answers)

You can't keep using it as "app.config". The .NET config system searches for the configuration file whose name is the same as the entry assembly. If you renamed the file back to "app.config", then the configuration classes would stop working.

Comment: Yes this is correct. One note though, how can I keep the file name as app.config?

Answer (score 1):

Your app.config file gets renamed on compilation, with the name of the binary. I.e. if your binary is myapp.exe then your app.config will be renamed to either myapp.config or myapp.exe.config.

This is the file that you should add to the setup package in order to use it on deployment for configuration.

Comment: Looks like this is the case. I was able to locate the file. Just wondering, why isn't the name kept app.config, or is it done for convenience.

Comment: @Gunner - imagine you're creating a suite of tools that you want to install into the same directory. They need a way of finding *their* config files, so that's why the config they look for is named the same as themselves + ".config". It's kept as app.config in the project because you can change the name of the output assembly at any time, in the project settings.

Comment: I suppose (but am not sure) that the config file is named according to the binary for convenience. Visual studio seems to prefer using the app.config, but after the project is compiled, it is renamed to *.exe.config. I suppose this is done in order to be able to have many binaries and configs in the same directory. Will have to look it up for the exact reason though.